# How to show my answer after few wrong attempt in HTML JavaScripts

Tags: javascript, html

1. Please help me to add a "Button" called "See your answer".
2. This "See your answer" button appear only after when user clicks "Check your answer" button 3 times, and 3 answers are wrong.
3. After click "See your answer" button, correct answer appear.
4. the correct answer is "100".

Thank you!!!

```html
<html>

<head>
<title> </title>
</head>

<body>

<p>How much is your profit?                                 

<input id="id1" name = "id1" required>
  <button  type = "button" onclick="myFunction()">Check Your Answer</button> </p>

<p id="Q1"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x, text;
    x = document.getElementById("id1").value;
   
    if (isNaN(x) || x != 100) {
        text = "Incorrect"; document.getElementById("Q1").style.color = "red";
    } else {
        text = "Correct"; document.getElementById("Q1").style.color = "green";
    }
    document.getElementById("Q1").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello,

See if it's what you need:

I put a global variable to be used as a counter.

I put a button to see the answer.

```
<html>

<head>
<title> </title>
</head>

<body>

<p>How much is your profit?

<input id="id1" name = "id1" required>
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Check Your Answer</button>         </p>
  <button type="button" id="btn2" onclick="seeYourAnswer()" style="display:none;">See your answer</button> </p>
<p id="Q1"></p>

<script>
var errosCount = 0;
function myFunction() {
    var x, text;
    x = document.getElementById("id1").value;

      if (isNaN(x) || x != 100) {
          text = "Incorrect"; document.getElementById("Q1").style.color = "red";
          errosCount++;
      } else {
          text = "Correct"; document.getElementById("Q1").style.color = "green";
      }
      document.getElementById("Q1").innerHTML = text;

      if(errosCount === 3){
        errosCount = 0;
        document.getElementById('btn2').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("Q1").innerHTML = '';
      } else {
        document.getElementById('btn2').style.display = 'none';        
      }

}

function seeYourAnswer(){
  text = "the correct answer is '100'.";         document.getElementById("Q1").style.color = "red";
  document.getElementById("Q1").innerHTML = text;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need is a little application state. You'll need a variable in your JavaScript along the lines of `numberOfSubmissions`. On your click handler for `Check Your Answer` increment `numberOfIncorrectSubmissions` if the answer is incorrect. After you increment, check if the value is 3 or higher. If it is, then show your `See the Answer` button.

Let me know if any of that is unclear or if you have trouble implementing.

Answer (score 0):

This is the idea. Try this out. Change the variable names and what not.

You need a global variable that will store the number of "attempts" in this case Y.

Every time you fail, Y is increased by 1.

There is an additional if statement on the function that if the fail equals to the about of "attempts", it will do something. You can make it do anything you want including resetting the attempt counter.

Cheers!

```
<head>
<title> </title>
</head>

<body>

<p>How much is your profit?                                 

<input id="id1" name = "id1" required>
  <button  type = "button" onclick="myFunction()">Check Your Answer</button> </p>

<p id="Q1"></p>
<p id="Q2"></p>

<script>

    var y=0;
function myFunction() {
    var x, text, text2;


    x = document.getElementById("id1").value;



    if (isNaN(x) || x != 100) {
      text = "Incorrect"; 
      document.getElementById("Q1").style.color = "red";
      y=y+1;
    }    
    else {
        text = "Correct"; 
        document.getElementById("Q1").style.color = "green";
    }

    if (y==3){
      text2 = "DONE"; 
      document.getElementById("Q2").style.color = "orange";
    }


    document.getElementById("Q1").innerHTML = text;
    document.getElementById("Q2").innerHTML = y;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a global variable that tracks the number of incorrect answers. I can't recite all of the reasons global variables are frowned upon, but basically they clutter the global namespace and could lead to conflicts, things like that. I hope this helps though.

```
<html>

<head>
<title> </title>
</head>

<body>

<p>How much is your profit?                                 

<input id="id1" name = "id1" required>
  <button  type = "button" onclick="myFunction()">Check Your Answer</button> </p>

<p id="Q1"></p>

<script>
var failedAttempts = 0;
function myFunction() {
    var x, text;
    x = document.getElementById("id1").value;

    if (failedAttempts === 3){
         // Show the answer
    }else if(isNaN(x) || x != 100) {
        text = "Incorrect"; document.getElementById("Q1").style.color = "red";
        failedAttempts++;
    } else {
        text = "Correct"; document.getElementById("Q1").style.color = "green";
    }
    document.getElementById("Q1").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```